# Trouble Validating form with Validate.js

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Im having trouble getting validate.js to work I have followed the documentation on the [github](https://github.com/rickharrison/validate.js/) and the form does not display any errors in console log or otherwise. How would I convey an error to the user?

Script

```
<script>
    var validator = new FormValidator('form1', [{
    name: 'address',
    rules: 'required'
}, {
    name: 'bedrooms',
    rules: 'required'
}, {
    name: 'bathrooms',
    rules: 'required'
}, {
    name: 'squareFootage',
    rules: 'required'

}], function(errors, event) {
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        // Show the errors
    }
});
```

Form

```
<form id="" name="form1" method="POST"
      action="page2.php" class="">
    <div class=" row input-append addressWrapper" id="fieldWrapper ">
        <input id="searchTextField" type="text" name="address"
               class="form1 request-input values address search-query"
               placeholder="Enter Your Address">
        <input type="hidden" name="type" id="changetype-all" checked="checked">
        <input type="hidden" name="city_image" id="city_image" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="lat" id="lat">
        <input type="hidden" name="lng" id="lng">
        <input type="hidden" name="submit" id="submit" class="">
    </div>
    <div class="row stats">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <select name="bedrooms" class="form3">
                <option selected value="">Bedrooms</option>
                <option value="0">0</option>

                <option value="1">1</option>

            </select></div>

        <div class="col-md-12">

            <select name="bathrooms" class="form3">
                <option selected value="">Bathrooms</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>


            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 marl ">

            <select name="squareFootage" class="form3">
                <option selected value="">Square Footage</option>
                <option value="0-800">0-800</option>

            </select>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" name="next" class="btn form1 btn-success worth p1" id="next"
                value="What's It Worth?">Submit
        </button>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Above closing body tag

```
  <script src="js/validate.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your callback needs to build the error message manually.

```
    function(errors, event) {
        // Show the errors
        if (errors.length > 0) {
          var tmpMsg = "";              
          for (var i = 0, errorLength = errors.length; i < errorLength; i++) {
              tmpMsg += '* ' + errors[i].message + '\n';
          }
          alert(tmpMsg);
        }
    });
```

Here's the working test page: 
http://jsfiddle.net/b10wrbdk/

gl.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about validate.js, but I just read the manual.

You are doing nothing with the errors, so nothing is happening.
This is your code:

```
 function(errors, event) {
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        // Show the errors
    }
 }
```

In the manual they give an example of what to do. Here it is:

```
function(errors, event) {
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        var errorString = '';

        for (var i = 0, errorLength = errors.length; i < errorLength; i++) {
            errorString += errors[i].message + '<br />';
        }

        el.innerHTML = errorString;
    }
}
```

Just substitute el in `el.innerHTML = errorString;` with a variable of your own, or just put `alert(errorString);` if you want to test it.